# Nexus 6 has Still not Received Android Marshmallow November Update

Tags: ota-update, side-loading

Whenever Google released Android Marshmallow, I sideloaded it on to my Nexus 6 using `adb sideload`. After the release of Android Marshmallow, it took Google a few days before they released the OTA update packs for the Nexus 6, but as soon as they did, I jumped on the opportunity to upgrade to build MRA58K.

Since then, Google has released the November update for Marshmallow (there are two builds listed [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images?hl=en) for the November update, MRA58N and MRA58R) but I have still not received the OTA for it by waiting.

Although I was patient, I'm somewhat concerned now that we are gearing up for the release of the December patches while I still haven't received the November patches.

Should I be concerned about this, or is this normal? I found a nice list [here](http://www.droidsec.org/news/2015/11/02/nexus-update-november-2015.html) of all the new builds added with the November update, and I'm unsure of whether I should sideload them or just wait in hopes of receiving the update in the standard way.

I also sideloaded the initial OTA for Marshmallow on my dad's Nexus 6, and he has also not received the update.

Comment: I usually get the updates within about a week of release on my Nexus 5. If you are unlocked and just one update behind, you might want to sideload it anyway. It should not make too much of a difference.

Comment: @AJDFHLOef That's what I did to get up to date. In the final days of Lollipop I was receiving OTAs within a week a well.